# "Project files" view in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android Studio, when you select "Project Files" in the "Project" section, you are presented with two folders rather than one:

- `ApplicationName`
- `app`

The `ApplicationName` folder lists all of the files and directories, except `app` which is taken out.

Questions:

- Is this because the `app` folder is particularly important?
- [Added] Are there cases where more than one folder is placed here (`app`, `app2`, ...)
- Is there any other "weirdness" I should be aware of in terms of what's displayed and how?
- Is this changeable in the settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The **app** directory is called modules where the modules are
>   the files/folders which built into the .apk files based on build
>   settings
>   Source:http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/tools/projects/index.html

These build settings can be changed "File->Project Structures-> Modules".
If you create/edit a module then changes will get reflect into "Run/Debug configuration" of your project under section Android Application.Without these module an apk can not be build in studio.

Comment: Sorry are you quoting the page? I cannot find your text anywhere